# How to get a number from a certain part of a string? (basic)

Tags: python, string

My code:

```
if x[6:7] == "0":
```

Basically `x = 0:00.0 (actual numbers vary)`

`x` is also a string. I need to take the last letter and check if it is `0` or not, but don't know how.

Comment: `str(x).endswith('0')`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as:

```
if x.split('.')[-1] == '0':
    #do something
```

If you ***literally*** mean the "last number", you can do that as:

```
if x[-1] == '0':
    #do something
```

You could also do:

```
if x.endswith('0'):
    #do something
```

#### Example

```
x = '0:00.0'
if x.split('.')[-1] == '0':
    print 'yes'

[OUTPUT]
yes
```

Comment: @user3553179, Glad I could help. If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? (After the time-limit is over, of course)

Comment: I would suggest `x.endswith('0') == True`

Comment: @aj8uppal, Thank you for your suggestion. I have included it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
x = "0:00.0"
match = str(re.findall("\d$",x))
if match == "0":
    print("it's zero")
else:
   print("not a zero")
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically if target string has fixed format, you can do like this.
It only works when last number is just one digit number.

```
>>> x = "0:00.0"
>>> if x[-1] == "0":
...     print "last number is 0"#do something
```

If target string is not fixed. You can do like this.
It works not only when last number is just one digit number but also multiple digit number

```
>>> x = "0:00.120"
>>> import re
>>> m = re.search(r'\d+$', x)
>>> if m and int(m.group(0)) == 0:
...     print "last number is 0"#do something
```